# Accrued Leave Credits

Tags: laravel

does someone has an idea on how to create a leave credits that will Accrued every month base on the day of Employee hired. like for example when the employee hired on February 24 then on March 24 the leave credits will start to accrued of 1.5 and then on April 24 another  1.5 credits will add.

this is my leave controller by the way

```
//leave Employee
public function leavesEmployee()
{
    $user = Auth::User()->rec_id;
    $credits = 0;
    $leaves = DB::table('leaves_admin')
                ->where('rec_id',Auth::user()->rec_id)
                ->get();
    return view('Leave.leaveEmployee', compact('leaves','user','credits'));
}
```

employee or user migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('rec_id');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('join_date')->unique();
        $table->string('status')->nullable();
        $table->string('role_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('needs_password')->default(false);
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

the join_date is the hire date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find the differences in months between the date of hired and the current date. Then apply your logic using difference months

For example

```
$hiredDate = Carbon::parse(Auth::user()->join_date);
$currentDate = Carbon::now();

if (!$hiredDate->isSameYear($currentDate)) {
    $hiredDate = $currentDate->copy()->startOfYear();
}

$diffInMonths = $currentDate->diffInMonths($hiredDate);

$credits = $diffInMonths * 1.5;

if($credits > 15 ) {
    $credits = 15;
}
```

**Update**

Credits will reset and return to 0 after the end of the current year. Also, when the credits reach 15 it will stop accumulating

Comment: i will try to implement this. thanks, it is my first time using carbon.
by the way, what if the credits will reset and go back to 0 after the year end? and also the leave credits has a limit of 15. so when the credits reach 15 it will stop the accrual

Comment: @Jay-arCristobal You said it, I did it. Now you can check it.